# Using Lie's Theorem to prove an ideal is nilpotent

Tags: lie-algebras

Let L be a finite-dim'l Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and I be a solvable ideal of L. Prove that the ideal [L,I] is nilpotent.

My reasoning:

Consider the adjoint representation $ad: I \rightarrow gl(L)$ defined by $ x \mapsto ad_{x}: y \mapsto [x,y]$.

I solvable $ \implies ad(I)$ is also solvable

Lie's Theorem $\implies \exists z \in L $ such that $ad_{x}(z) = [x,z]=\lambda_{x}z$ $\forall x \in L$.

Now, to show that $[L,I]$ is nilpotent: Let $u_1,u_2 \in I$ and $v_1,v_2 \in L$.

$\left[[u_1,v_1],[u_2,v_2] \right]$

This is where I get stuck. I know that I need to show that $[I,L]^{n}={0}$ for some $n$ using the fact that there is a common simultaneous eigenvector but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Let $rad(L)$ denote the sovable radical of $L$, i.e., the maximal solvable ideal of $L$. We have $I\subseteq rad(L)$, since $I$ is solvable. Now we can use the result $$[L,rad(L)]\subseteq nil(L),$$
where $nil(L)$ is the nilradical. The proof given [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=95lyvIfX164C&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=let+I+be+a+solvable+ideal+of+Lie+algebra+L.+Show+with+Lie%27s+theorem+that+[L,A]+is+nilpotent&source=bl&ots=H3MHQdxp0z&sig=aYF9ruZJWtiaGq8EzKwTa4FTZFI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHoPyWo__LAhXoO5oKHR-5DtMQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=let%20I%20be%20a%20solvable%20ideal%20of%20Lie%20algebra%20L.%20Show%20with%20Lie%27s%20theorem%20that%20[L%2CA]%20is%20nilpotent&f=false) (which comes even before Lie's theorem) uses that all adjoint operators $ad_{[L,rad(L)]}(x)$ are nilpotent, so that $[L,rad(L)]$ is a nilpotent ideal by Engel's theorem.
In particular, $[L,I]\subseteq nil(L)$ is a nilpotent ideal of $L$.

Comment: Thank you! We haven't learned about nilradicals yet. Do you have any hints of a way to show this using Lie's theorem?

Comment: You don't need the nilradical. It is enough to show that all $ad_{[L,rad(L)]}(x)$ are nilpotent, so that Engel's theorem gives you the result. Here you can use Lie's theorem.

Comment: Here's my attempt:

Consider the adjoint representation
$ad:[L,rad(L)] \rightarrow gl(L)$ defined by $ad_{[x,y]}(z)=[[x,y],z]$

Then $ \{ad_{[x,y]} : x \in L, y \in rad(L) \}$ is solvable and Lie's Thm $\implies $ there is some $ v \in L$ such that $[[x,y],v]=\lambda_{[x,y]}v$ for all $[x,y] \in [L,rad(L)]$